# Convert multiple es6 to multiple es5 file in order to create npm package

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, ecmascript-6, browserify

I have written some react components.

I have a folder of ES6 files with multiple files :

- components/A.js
- components/Button.js

I wan't to import them like this in my futur project.

```
 import A from 'bootstrap-styled/components/A';
```

I would like to create a npm package.

I need to export them in ES5 format using the SAME directory structure.

I don't wan't a single output file.

Is there any existing program that can do that ?

Comment: "I don't wan't a single output file" -  it looks like you confused the Babel with the Webpack. In your case, enough Babel - just to compile all ES6 files into ES5 with same folder structure. If this is your case I'll write an answer based on Babel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have `Babel` installed in you project (I assume that it is already installed because without it you would not be able to run your ES6 in the browser. So I omit all the settings of Babel, just make sure that you have `babel-cli` in your project).

So all you need is:

```
babel components --out-dir dist
```

It will compile all your files from `components` to `dist`.
Than you can publish it to NPM with

`"main": "dist"`

in your `package.json`

If you are looking for automatisation of this process try this boilerplate project -
[react-cdk](https://github.com/kadirahq/react-cdk).
It'll do the exactly you asking: compile ES6 to ES5 every time you run `npm publish`

Comment: I will try it out, the only thing I see to use react-cdk is how to add my dependencies to this project. I use styled-component over react

Comment: You may start new project with react-cdk and then setup your package.json and install all dependencies as usual. in general there should be no problems with it.